# Creating RSA key using an external source of random number (Java)

Tags: java, security, cryptography, rsa

I had generate a 256 bits random keys into a file.

The plan is to using the 256 bits random key as a source to generate a RSA (public and private) key.

Anyone kind soul know how I can do it?

Comment: Just a note: RSA keys are usually much longer than that (at least 1024 bits is common), and need correspondingly more random bits to be really secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can generate keys using [KeyPairGenerator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html), which can be initialized with [SecureRandom](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html). `SecureRandom` has constructor which takes array of bytes as seed.